# How to move between several tables without using joins

Tags: join, expression, ms-access-2013

I need to "Display all the columns of Employee for those employees who invoiced a vehicle that was owned by a dealership that is different than the dealership that the employee works for."

I'm not allowed to use joins to answer this question so I'm a little confused as to how to get all the information from these tables. I'd need to see if an employee invoiced a vehicle, then determine which dealership that vehicle is sold at, then determine if that dealerships id code is the same as the employees id code.

What are some possible alternatives to using join.

Invoice, Employee, Dealership, and Vehicle are each their own table.

Comment: if this is a school problem, try using one or two subqueries instead of a join.

Comment: We're not going to be able to answer this question without knowing the relationships between those tables. If I assume the invoice table has foreign keys to the vehicles, employee, and dealership tables, we can take my answer below, but change 'Vehicles' to 'Invoice'.

Comment: Sorr should have included that. Employee uses edcode as a foreign key to dealership. Invoice uses ieid as a foreign key to Employee and ivin as a foreign key to vehicle. Vehicle uses vdcode as a foreign key to dealership.

Comment: I updated my answer. I used 'employeeID' and 'vehicleID', but use whatever the primary keys are called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested statements are a possible alternative.

```
select * from Employees e
where employeeID is in
    (select ieid from Invoice
    where ivin is in
        (select vehicleID from Vehicle
        where vdcode <> e.edcode))
```